# Help with Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find some patterns. they can be:

```
1. "fourty|40;TOFIND|1234;fifty|50"
2. "TOFIND|1234;fifty|50"
3. "fourty|40;TOFIND|1234"
```

as you can see, the TOFIND|1234 can appear inside the statement (before ; and after ;), or it can have only before ; or it can have none.

It should NOT include examples:

```
MTOFIND|1234;
;TOFIND|1234Q
```

How can I find it?

I tried:
Regex re = new Regex("TOFIND|1234" + "[;?]");

But I am not sure its correct.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: You should propose what some negative samples could be, e.g., what if there was XTOFIND|1234, or TOFIND|12345.

Comment: would you like to extract the TOFIND from the line? Or do you want to get only those lines that have TOFIND in it?

Comment: I need it to support only beginning is empty, end is empty or ; before or ; at the end

Answer (score 1):

What about any character before or after the exact string *TOFIND|1234*?

```
Regex re = new Regex(".*(TOFIND\|1234).*");
```

Comment: Not allowed. Only ^ or $ (respectively) or only ; that can appear at the beginning or end

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex re = new Regex("(?:[^;])TOFIND\|1234(?=[;$])");
```

Answer (score 0):

You my try this:
";?TOFIND|1234;?"
This will include ";"s in the match.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
string FindIt(string inStr)
{
    for each (string item in inStr.Split(new char [] {';'}))
    {
       string [] eles = item.Split(new char [] {'|'});
         if (eles[0] == "TOFIND")
           return eles[1];
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the lines that contain TOFIND

```
@"TOFIND\|.*|.*;TOFIND.*"
```

I found this tool over here to be of great help:
[Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and edits, here we go... This is the `Regex` that you could use:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@";?[^\w](TOFIND\|1234)[^\w];?");
```

So, using the folowing samples:

```
1. "fourty|40;TOFIND|1234;fifty|50"
2. "TOFIND|1234;fifty|50"
3. "fourty|40;TOFIND|1234"
4. "MTOFIND|1234;"
5. ";TOFIND|1234Q"
6. "some|15;TOFIND|1234;"
7. ";TOFIND|1234;blabla|100"
```

It will match the lines `1`, `2`, `3`, `6` and `7`.

Let's explain the rules:

```
";?"  // We need 0 or 1 semi-colon before.
"[^\w]"  // We can't have any char (a-zA-Z0-9) before.
"(TOFIND\|1234)"  // We must have exactly TOFIND|1234.
"[^\w]"  // We can't have any char after.
";?"  // We need 0 or 1 semi-colon after.
```

If I understood well all your needs, thats it.